# Batch - Remove Range/specific words

Tags: batch-file, perforce, changelist, unshelve

In perforce I print the list of shelved/changes to the file with the following batch script :

```
for %%A IN (%ShelvedCHL%) DO (
    echo Change List: %%A 
    p4 -p %PPort% -c %PClient% unshelve -s %%A && if NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 exit -1
)>> list.txt
```

Here is my list.txt

Change List: 24536

```
//GSA/TOC.h#1 - unshelved, opened for edit
... /GSA/TOC.h - also opened by test@dev
... /GSA/TOC.h - also opened by test@dev
//odata/oenums.h#6 - unshelved, opened for edit
... //odata/oenums.h#6 - also opened by test@dev
```

I want to have the following output, basically remove sentence after - with dash as well : or even any perforce command to have less information and just list of files :

```
 //GSA/TOC.h#1 
 ... /GSA/TOC.h
 ... /GSA/TOC.h
 //odata/oenums.h#6
 ... //odata/oenums.h#6
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in `p4` natively without doing hardly any scripting at all.  Check out this blog post:

https://www.perforce.com/blog/fun-formatting

You can see the fields in a Perforce message by running it with the `-e` global opt*, like this:

`p4 -e files ...`

Then you can use any or all of those fields when reformatting the output, like this:

`p4 -F "just the filename please: %depotFile%" files ...`

*see also `-Ztag` which gives you an alternate dictionary of output fields

Answer (score 1):

At first, let us take a look at your code:

1. I do not know the program `p4`, but I assume it is setting the [`ErrorLevel`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html). So since this value is updated in the same block of code as you want to read it, you need to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), so place `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` on top of your script and use `!ErrorLevel!` instead of `%ErrorLevel%`. Another way is to replace `if not !ErrorLevel!==0` by [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)`not ErrorLevel 1`, meaning *if `ErrorLevel` is not greater than and not equal to `1`*, or expressed in a simpler way, *if `ErrorLevel` is less than `1`*, but this works only if the program does not set a negative value.
2. Even if you corrected the `ErrorLevel` issue, the `if` query would never eb executed because of the [conditional command concatenation operator `%%`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), because this lets the following command only execute in case the preceding one succeeded, meaning that its exit code<sup>1</sup> equals zero. Therefore to execute the `if` statement, use the unconditional operator `&`. Anyway, there is also another conditional operator `||`, which lets the following command only execute in case the exit code is a non-zero value; this one could replace your `if` condition completely.
3. The `exit` command does not only quit the batch file, it also terminates the command prompt (`cmd`) instance which the batch script ran in. To quit the batch file only use `exit /B` instead.
4. You are setting the `ErrorLevel` to `-1` by `exit -1`. You can do this, of course, but usually negative values are avoided; hence let me suggest a positive value like `1` (by `exit /B 1`).
5. You are opening and closing the file `list.txt` for every single iteration of the [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html). This reduces overall performance. Furthermore, if `list.txt` already exists, the data becomes appended; if you do not want that you need to place `del "list.txt" 2> nul` before the `for` loop to initially delete the file. Anyway, to write the entire file at once, put another pair of parentheses around the `for` loop. You can then chose whether to append to an already existing file using the [redirection operator `>>`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), or to overwrite it using operator `>` (without any need to delete it first).

All this results in the following improved script:

```cmd
(for %%A in (%ShelvedCHL%) do (
    echo Change List: %%A 
    p4 -p %PPort% -c %PClient% unshelve -s %%A || exit /B 1
)) > "list.txt"
```

Depending on what `%ShelvedCHL%` contains (it seems to be `24536` in your sample data, so not a file path/name/mask), the `for` loop might even be superfluous, although I cannot know at this point...

---

Anyway, all of the above does still not yet account for removal of the partial string beginning with <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `-` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, so let us implement this now:

To keep it simple, we could just modify the file `list.txt` after the above code, using this code (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks; the mentioned string manipulation is called [sub-string substitution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)):

```cmd
rem // Read file `list.txt` line by line:
(for /F "usebackq delims= eol=|" %%L in ("list.txt") do (
    rem // Assign line string to variable:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Enable delayed expansion to be able to do string manipulation:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Replace every occurrence of ` - ` by a single character `|`, then use this one
    rem    as a delimiter to split the line string as `for /F` requires single-character
    rem    delimiters; just using `-` is not good as they might occur in the partial
    rem    strings that need to be kept, I suppose; the `|` must not occur in them: */
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=| eol=|" %%K in ("!LINE: - =|!") do (
        rem // Disable delayed expansion to not lose `!`-marks:
        endlocal
        rem // Return the split string, that is the part before the (first) ` - `:
        echo %%K
    )
)) > "list_NEW.txt"
```

The resulting data is contained in the file `list_NEW.txt`. To have it in the original file, append the following line to the code:

```cmd
move /Y "list_NEW.txt" "list.txt" > nul
```

---

<sub>1... Usually the exit code and `ErrorLevel` are the same, but there are in fact some rare cases where they may differ.</sub>